# How to write script to auto submit to scuttle sites?

Tags: php

I'm looking to see if it's possible for me to code something maybe in php to auto submit a link into a scuttle site. Maybe a bookmarklet, or maybe just a script. Any ideas?

Update: I am not trying to write a virus. I just have a bunch of accounts on social bookmarking sites, and I'm tired of clicking through a lot of forms to submit something.

Comment: Still sounds fishy like spamming.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is posible. But to do that you will have to study about the site and how it works. I would suggest you to go to http://forums.digitalpoint.com/ and search there as this forum has lot of posts about the script you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

You can used dome for submit 10 scuttle site
http://forums.digitalpoint.com/showthread.php?t=1178715

Answer (score 0):

Scuttle implements the [Delicious API](http://www.delicious.com/help/api) to add posts.